# Як позначати вставлені слова і речення, коли не визначено інтонацію?

Tags: пунктуація, синтаксис

Вставлені слова і речення можна виділяти комами, тире, дужками, комою з тире. Який знак використати, залежить від інтонації. 
Ось, наприклад, правила:

- Якщо вставлене речення вимовляється майже таким самим тоном, як і основне, то воно виділяється з обох боків **комами**.

  > Звали нашого діда, як я вже потім довідавсь, Семеном.
- Якщо вставлені слова чи речення вимовляються підвищеним тоном, то вони виділяються з обох боків **тире**.

  > В щирім серці, в чесних грудях — вірю, знаю! — квіти є!
- Якщо вставлена конструкція виділяється тире й уводиться в речення на тому місці, де за правилами вживається кома, то така конструкція виділяється з обох боків **комами та тире**:

  > Не було ще такого літнього ранку, — хіба вже каміння з неба, — щоб дід Арсен, прозваний Бушлею, всидів дома.
- Найчастіше вставлені слова чи речення вимовляються пониженим тоном. Тоді вони виділяються **дужками**.

  > Далеко-далеко (те знають хіба що лелеки) розкидала доля киптарики і сіряки.

**Моє питання полягає в наступному:**

Якщо я не знаю, яка там має бути інтонація, як варто виділяти ці конструкції, щоб не помилитися? Наприклад, при виконанні письмового завдання. Інтуїтивно?